# Binary operation, function composition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ is the set of all bijective functions $f:\{1,2\} \to \{1,2\}$ , how do we prove that function composition is a binary operation on $A$?

I know that function composition is a binary operation on a set $A$ where $A$ is the set of all functions, but how do you prove it for all bijective functions?

Would a better place to start be to list all of the possible elements of $A$?

Answer (score 2):

In this case you only have two bijections: 
$$f=\{(1,1),(2,2)\},g=\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$$
All you need to do is show that $f \circ g$ , $g \circ f$, $f \circ f$ , $g \circ g$ are in $A$.
$$f \circ g = \{(1,2),(2,1)\}=g \in A$$
$$g \circ f = \{(1,2),(2,1)\}=g \in A$$
$$f \circ f = \{(1,1),(2,2)\}=f \in A$$
$$g \circ g = \{(1,1),(2,2)\}=f \in A$$

Comment: How are f and g bijections?

Comment: I wrote them as relations from $A \times A$. It means: $f(1)=g(2)=1$, $f(2)=g(1)=2$. Fine now?

Comment: @ncm I meant $\{1,2\} \times \{1,2\}$, not $A \times A$..

Answer (score 1):

You can list the bijections in this case, but the general case is not much harder. You have to show that given two bijections from $A$ to $A$, their composition is a bijection as well.

And that follows from the general theorem that a composition of bijections is a bijection (and if you don't know that, you should sit down to prove that, because it's important.)

Comment: Proving it is even less tedious than listing all of the compositions.. :-)

Comment: How would you prove that the composition of bijections is a bijection? Which general thereom is that?

Comment: Show that if $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to C$ are injective functions, then their composition is an injection; and if the functions are surjective, then their composition is surjective.